# ADB debugging not turning on Chromebook

Tags: android, adb, chromebook

So, I've turned on the 'Linux Development environment' on my Chromebook and I've wanted to install a few of the Apps I've been making for Android. sadly I didn't have an android phone, So I thought that maybe I could try it on my Chromebook,So I have installed ADB and then I ran a command -

```
adb connect arc
```

and well I ran into an error -

```
missing port in specification: tcp:arc
```

. So I kept looking for a solution and somebody else had the same problem, some people said that we should turn on ADB debugging. And well the tutorial I've been following (I didn't find the link for the tutorial , but I do know the steps) said that ADB debugging would Found in Setting>Advanced>Developers>Linux development environment>Develop Android Apps>Enable ADB debugging, but there was a ***problem***, whenever I clicked the button to turn this feature on(switch) it does not move. I have also tried turning off and turning on the Linux development environment but still it doesn't work [image: when trying to click on the Switch/Button it doesn't turn on.]

If anybody knows the solution, **Please tell me**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar situation, and I suspect it is related to the update of ChromeOS.

Compared with the [official guidance](https://chromeos.dev/en/android-environment/deploying-apps), it seems that you can install your App directly without `adb connect arc`.